# Repeating alarm on specified days

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So let's say my site gets updated every Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday. I don't know the exact time of those updates, so I would like to do polling every hour to check if new content is available. What would be the best way to do this? Only 2 things I can think of:

- repeating the alarm every 1 hour at all times, check if the day is Tuesday, Thursday or Saturday and if it is, then do the polling from the server.
- setting a repeating alarm at BOOT_COMPLETED for AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY with HOUR_OF_DAY and MINUTE set to zero. every time the alarm gets fired check if it's Tuesday, Thursday or Saturday. if true, set another repeating alarm with a 1 hour interval.

Any other, possibly more elegant ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a receiver for boot completed, and every time set an alarm for the next relevant day at 12:00am.
Use Calendar to get days.
Then in the service that you start set a new alarm for every hour, until 11:59 pm. The alarm at 11:59 pm would then set an Alarm for the next appropriate day.

I would reccomend using a BroadcastReceiver with the pending Intent for the alarms which will start a service if the time is right.

Remember, it may be good to use a partial_wakelock